# Accessing key:values within a string

Tags: python

I have data parsed from a log file in the following format

```
{ topic: { name: "foo", other: "bar:more" }}
```

Is there a way for me to access the values by key? As keys do not contain quotes I don't see how to convert to a dict or JSON for example. I have the added headache that some values contain ":" in their value also.

Comment: You should configure the logging so it uses a json compatible format. Otherwise you have to parse it manually.

Comment: Do you have any control over the logfile format?

Comment: No, I cannot change how the logs are generated